# how to Iterate through an arrayList of object and find duplicates in object properties?

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, duplicates, iteration

I have the following class:

```
class A {
    ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<>();
    double d = Double.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

I've an arrayList of class A like `ArrayList<A> alist = new ArrayList<>();`
In `alist`I have some elements like followings:

```
[[b  c]  1.3]
[[c  d]  0.2]
[[c  b  o]  0.9]
[[x  o  j]  1.8]
[[c  d]  1.7]
[[b  c  o]  2.2]
[[f  p  n]  1.1]
and so on...
```

All I need is to iterate through this `alist`and check if there any duplicates in String list of `class A` object. If so then preserve only one element and add others d values with its d value and remove other elements from `alist`which have the same String list. For example:
from the above list we can see 2nd and 5th elements have duplicate string list so add their values and preserve only one of them with that added value and remove others. Same as, element 3rd and 6th has same String list(string order is not important in inner string list). So for the above list, the expected output will be:

```
[[b  c]  1.3]
[[c  d]  1.9]
[[b  c  o]  3.1]
[[x  o  j]  1.8]
[[f  p  n]  1.1]
```

Can anybody help me with this by providing some sample code please? I'm not that good in Java. So please pardon me if I made any mistake!

Thanks!

Comment: Very good and interesting question. Just show us what you've tried and we'll assist you even more.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start would be defining what the .equals() method does in class A. Then it is just as easy as iterating over your collection, and asking if a.eqauls(b).

Comment: This should really be a comment, not an answer!

Comment: So what is the correct answer to this question? Providing answers to questions like this with full working  code is considered bad practice on SO

Comment: @adarshr I still lack the reputation to be able to comment anywhere.. 

flyleaf - do you still need help with this?