# how can Ikeep one and remove other duplicate arrayList objects and update another object property?

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I need your help in JAVA (with some sample code if possible) regarding to the following scenario:
I have a list with a classes object and want to check if one object property has duplicates then
 keep one of them and add others amounts with the kept one's amount. For example:

I have this class:

```
class Salary {
    String names;
    Double amount;
}
```

and the list say `salary_list` contains the following elements in it(for example):

```
[jony,john   300.96]
[fuse,norvi,newby  1000.55]
[john,jony  22.6]
[richard,ravi,navin  55.6]
[fuse,norvi,newby  200.6]
... ... ...
```

So what is my expected output is the same input list with the following revised result:

```
[jony,john  323.56]
[fuse,norvi,newby  1201.15]
[richard,ravi,navin  55.6]
```

**N.B**: order in names is not important so not the order of the elements after the duplicate elimination.
I am not good at english as well as in Java. So forgive me if any mistakes there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the name a concatenated string of first name and last name seperated by comma? also "jony,john" and "john,jony" are same in your case?

Comment: thanks for your reply. this is not first or last name. these are different peoples names. and "jony,john" and "john,jony" are same in my case. I am not thinking of the order of the peoples(comma seperated) in the total string.

Comment: What happens if the list contains `[john,fuse 100]`? Do you have to handle that condition, or detect it as an error?

Comment: I have a feeling I've [seen similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056752/how-to-iterate-through-an-arraylist-of-object-and-find-duplicates-in-object-prop). Is it me or is it homework?

Comment: @JimGarrison: this wouldn't be an error. there no relation between the elements string property except they have the same comma separated names

Comment: @Pshemo: saw the question of your given link. quite similar but i have not found any ans there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enhance your `Salary` class as follows:

```
class Salary {
    String names;
    Double amount;
    private String sortedNames = null;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        if (o == null || ! (o instanceof Salary)) return false;
        Salary othr = (Salary) o;
        String thisNames = this.getSortedNames();
        String othrNames = othr.getSortedNames();
        return thisNames.equals(othrNames);
    }

    @Override 
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return getSortedNames().hashCode();
    }

    public String getSortedNames()
    {
        if (this.sortedNames == null)
        {
            String[] nameArr = this.names.split(",");
            Arrays.sort(nameArr);
            StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
            for (String n : nameArr)
                buf.append(",").append(n);
            this.sortedNames = buf.substring(buf.length()==0?0:1);
        }

        return this.sortedNames; 
    }
}
```

This assumes that `Salary` is immutable (that is, after it's created the values of `names` and `amount` won't change.  You could then use this with a hash map to add up all the amounts having the same names.

```
    Map<String,Salary>  map  = new HashMap<String,Salary>();
    for (Salary s : list)
    {
        Salary e = map.get(s.getSortedNames());
        if (e == null)
            map.put(s.getSortedNames(), s);
        else
            e.amount += s.amount;
    }
```

At this point the `map` contains all unique `Salary` objects with the total amount for each.

Answer (score 0):

You have few very helpful tools in Java. You can

- split String into array defining separator like `"jony,john".split(",")` will give you array {"jony","john"}
- sort data in arrays by `Arrays.sort(arrayToSort)`
- compare if arrays are equal (contain same values with same order) by `Arrays.equals(array1, array2)` or by comparing its String representation using `Arrays.toString(array)`
- use Maps (like HashMap) to hold pairs [key -> value]

With these you can solve your problem.

Tip: You can use Map like `<String, Double>` to count your data. As key (String) you can use sorted representation of names. If Map already contains some sorted representation of names then increase value stored under that key.